# How to get a selected value from HTML and handle it in js or php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, filtering

I have created an array of events and now I have a filter by location dropdown. How do I get the value selected in the dropdown and handle it in js or php? Which one would it be better so it shows events from that location and not all the events. I have have different files one for displaying the events (events.js and events.php) and the other files (filterevents.js and filter events.php) this is what I want to handle the filtering in.

HTML

```
         <div class="events">

             <form method="POST" id="eventForm"> 
                 Filter By Location<br/>
                <select name="Locations">
                    <option value="Leeds">Leeds</option>
                    <option value="Newcastle">Newcastle</option>
                    <option value="London">London</option>
                </select>
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
             </form>

                    <div class="eventname"><!--obj.eventname--></div>
                    <div class="date"><!--obj.date--></div>
                    <div class="time"><!--obj.time--></div>
                    <div class="location"><!--obj.location--></div>

                <p id="error" class="errormessage"></p>
                <p id="allevents" class="postmessage"></p>
        </div>
```

events.php

```
<?php

require_once('checklog.php');
require_once("db_connect.php");
require_once("functions.php");

session_start();

// Print out existing events
$query = "SELECT eventname, date, time, location FROM events ORDER BY eventname";
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if (!$result)
    die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $events[] = $row; 

}

mysqli_free_result($result);

require_once("db_close.php");

echo json_encode($events);

?>
```

events.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var events = document.getElementById("allevents").value; 

        // Call Ajax for existing comments
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'events.php',
        success: function(result) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(result);

                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var obj = arr[i];   

                var output = document.getElementById("allevents");  

                output.innerHTML += '<div class="comment-container"><div class="eventname">'+obj.eventname+'</div><div class="date">'+obj.date+'</div><div class="time">'+obj.time+'</div><div class="location">'+obj.location+'</div></div>';

            }
        }
    });
```

filterevents.php

```
<?php

require_once('checklog.php');
require_once("db_connect.php");
require_once("functions.php");

This is where I want to filter but not sure how to do it.

?>
```

filterevents.js

```
// When post button is clicked
$(document).ready(function() {
    var forum = $("#eventForm");
    $("#eventForm").on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var events = new FormData(this); 

    if (events) {

    // Call Ajax for new comment
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'filterevents.php',
        data: events, 
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
                if(response == "Success")  
                {
                  document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = response;
                } else { 
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = response;
                } 
            } 
        });
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please Select A Location";
    }        
    return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: `if (!$result)
    die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $events[] = $row; 

}` < Let's study that. If there are no results, you make it `die()`. Now, how do you expect your `while` loop to continue?

Comment: `if()` < I don't know why you left that hanging like that.

Comment: `WHERE location = ‘LEEDS’` < that contains curly quotes and should be getting an parse error back for it.

Comment: `$username = $_POST['username'];` < I don't see you using that anywhere. Your question contains too many syntax errors and unknowns.

Comment: I have removed this out for now as obvs I won't be using that. This is why I asked the Q in the first place to find out how I would go about doing it. @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I have removed all irrelevant code.

Comment: Enable error reporting and error handling on all queries. I am not a JS guy, so if this is JS related, I am not the guy for this, sorry. I am mostly a serverside coder.